# Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui-search-bar'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting the error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui-search-bar' in 'C:\Users\James\React\fpl-ui\src'
```

When running `npm start` on Windows.

However the exact same project compiles and runs fine on OSX do I'm not sure if there's some kind of Windows specific configuration that I am missing.

My package.json has the following dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.3.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-script": "^2.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  }
```

I've tried removed one of the `material-ui` dependencies but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Did you install locally or globally when you ran npm install? It is likely that it is a problem with how npm is resolving folders that might contain modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`material-ui-search-bar` is not a part of the `@material-ui` package you need to install this package separately:

```
npm install --save material-ui-search-bar
```

Aside from that, it's weird that you have both `@material-ui/core` and `material-ui` installed at the same time. They are both the same packages but from different major releases.

**EDIT:** I now understand why you are using these two version concurently. The current stable release of `material-ui-search-bar` is using the old material-ui version. Fortunately the beta release channel does supports the new version.

I would advice you to do the following:

- Remove the old `material-ui` version, and only keep the new one `@material-ui/core`.

  ```
  npm uninstall --save material-ui
  ```
- Remove the old `material-ui-search-bar`:

  ```
  npm uninstall --save material-ui-search-bar
  ```
- Install the beta release for `material-ui-search-bar`

  ```
  npm install --save material-ui-search-bar@1.0.0-beta.13
  ```

Now it should work, but i would be a good idea to take a look at the documentation for the `material-ui-search-bar` package to see if the new version has introduced some API changes.

Usually it's not advisable to use the latest beta release as it's prone to be buggy, but in this case looking at the changelog it seems safer. Also take a look at the new release of this package to update it once in a while.

At the end of the process your package.json should look something like this.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.3.2",
    "material-ui-search-bar": "1.0.0-beta.13"
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-script": "^2.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
}
```

Comment: That worked! Now I get the same error about @material-ui/core/Paper module not being found, but that one looks like it is part of @material-ui/core which I already have as a dependency, so a bit confused as to how to install that one.

Comment: As i said, the dual material-ui is kind of confusing, try to remove `material-ui` and only keep the `@material-ui/core`. If that does not works, have you added the dependencies manually or was it added automatically by `npm install` ?

Comment: That kind of worked, now I'm getting the error `./node_modules/material-ui-search-bar/lib/components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/AutoComplete' in 'C:\Users\James\React\fpl-ui\node_modules\material-ui-search-bar\lib\components\SearchBar'` I'm a bit confused by this.

Comment: @JaAnTr my bad, i forgot to add the `--save` to the uninstall command, now the package should have been unnistalled but i believe that `package.json` still contains it. Remove `material-ui` from package.json (don't remove @material-ui/core nor material-ui-search-bar)

Answer (score 0):

your package.json is missing `material-ui-search-bar` package. Please run `npm i --save material-ui-search-bar` to install dependency in your project locally and then run `npm start` again.

If it doesn't work, check your package.json file again and make sure `material-ui-search-bar` is added as dependency. If its not, you can try to add it manually and then run `npm install` and `npm start` again.

Comment: while adding manually what version should I choose.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the command `npm install` inside app root folder. This is will add all required dependencies that are missed.